# Ajax sortable not firing

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I have a brief simple exemplar of code to create a sortable list. The ajax isn't firing in either firefox or chrome (os/x). Firebug and chrome tools show no errors, the applicable js files present in the correct order, and yet holding the mouse over the handle (or anywhere in the row prior to specifying a handle) only gave me a text bar, and dragging just highlighted the text.

I've tried this using a table and making the tbody sortable, and now, instead, div's.

The versions of jquery, jquery ui and jquery cookie are the defaults at each site as of today.

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin-faq.js"></script>

<title>Admin - FAQ</title>

<link href="/css/admin-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body id="public">
  <div id='faq'>
    <div id='data'>
      <div>
        <div class='handle'>+</div>
        <div class='q'>test ...ion 1</div>
        <div class='links'><a title='$q' href='$PHP_SELF?mode=edit&id=$row_array[0]'>edit</a></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class='handle'>+</div>
        <div class='q'>test ...ion 2</div>
        <div class='links'><a title='$q' href='$PHP_SELF?mode=edit&id=$row_array[0]'>edit</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

admin-faq.js

```
$('#faq #data').sortable({
  containment: "parent",
  axis: "y",
  cursor: "move",
  helper: "clone"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed a function wrapper around the jQuery.